# Finding the last remaining vector in the matrix Null Space

Tags: linear-algebra

I am solving some very peculiar quantum mechanical problem, and in order to do that I need to compute the nullspace of a matrix representing the effective Hamiltonian of the system considered.

The problem is that solving this problem directly analytically for a system of an arbitrary size (that's the goal) is quite challenging, however, I can start from some trivial cases, and try to solve the problem iteratively by obtaining some kind of a recurrence relation.

Consider a square strictly lower triangular matrix $\mathbf{A^{(N-1)}}$ for which I know the Null Space exactly. $N$ here is just a parameter (number of particles) that defines the dimensions of $\mathbf{A^{(N-1)}}$. Now I consider the matrix of the same operator for a slightly larger system:

$$\mathbf{A^{(N)}} = \begin{pmatrix}
\mathbf{A^{(N-1)}} & \mathbf{0} \\
\mathbf{L} & \mathbf{D}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

where $\mathbf{D}$ is a square strictly lower diagonal matrix, $\mathbf{L}$ is some matrix of no observable symmetry, and $\mathbf{0}$ is a matrix of zeros.
The operator $\mathbf{A}$ has a very nice property: all of the vectors from the nullspace of $\mathbf{A^{(N-1)}}$ also belong to the nullspace $\mathbf{A^{(N)}}$, and I also know that there is exactly $1$ additional vector in the nullspace of $\mathbf{A^{(N)}}$.

My question is: could the knowledge about the nullspace of $\mathbf{A^{(N-1)}}$ help me to find the remaining vector to construct the nullspace of $\mathbf{A^{(N)}}$?